# Cordova Unfortunaly, HelloWorld has stopped

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu-14.04

i try to use cordova in Ubuntu 14.04 for create a simple android app. I create the first project using

`cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`

i add the android platform, i try to build and build success, but when i emulate the app don't start and receive the error on screen

*Unfortunaly, HelloWorld has stopped.*

All the solution i have found don't work.

This is the code autocreated from cordova.

```
package com.example.hello;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class HelloWorld extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using phonegap (build on Cloud) or the local implementation?

Comment: the local implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try with:
Try replacing

> index.html

for the name of your page.

```
public class enlacedata extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        //super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //Change your index.html for your page name
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: is your referenced page in the path: `assets/www/index.html` ?

Comment: run de commands:
`phonegap build android && phonegap run android`